# Dart/Flutter - Why the output is null?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a class of questions in `String` and answers in `bool`.

The code is:

```
  List<Questions> questionsList = [
    Questions(q: 'I am a male', a: true),
    Questions(q: 'I am a female', a: false),
    Questions(q: 'My crush is a male',a:  false),
    Questions(q: 'My crush is a female',a:  true),
    Questions(q: 'I am gorgeous',a:  true),
  ];


  int questionNumber = 0;
  print(questionsList[questionNumber].questionText);
}

class Questions {
  String questionText;
  bool questionAnswer;

  Questions({String q, bool a}){
    q = questionText;
    a = questionAnswer;
  }
}
```

But, why is the output of `print(questionsList[questionNumber].questionText);` is `null`?
Is there anyone who could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the class set up incorrectly. It should be:

```
class Questions {
  String questionText;
  bool questionAnswer;

  Questions({String q, bool a}){
    this.questionText = q;
    this.questionAnswer = a;
  }
}
```

I'd also like to demonstrate a shorter and convenient way by using named parameters.

```
List<Questions> questionsList = [
    Questions(questionText: 'I am a male', questionAnswer: true),
    Questions(questionText: 'I am a female', questionAnswer: false),
    Questions(questionText: 'My crush is a male',questionAnswer: false),
    Questions(questionText: 'My crush is a female',questionAnswer:  true),
    Questions(questionText: 'I am gorgeous',questionAnswer:  true),
  ];


  int questionNumber = 0;
  print(questionsList[questionNumber].questionText);


}

class Questions {
  String questionText;
  bool questionAnswer;

  Questions({ this.questionText, this.questionAnswer });
}
```